# How to use sysprep for a vhd

Tags: windows, hyper-v, vhd, sysprep

We have a vhd copy of physical a windows vista machine. Since we don't want to touch the physical machine, we like to run sysprep on the vhd. Unfortunately this vhd does not boot on hyper-v. Is there a way to sysprep this vhd without booting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sysprep runs in a booted windows environment.  No.  Click [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766514%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for a thorough sysprep guide.

You could convert the vhd to another type like vmdk and try booting the vmdk instead.